# How to initialize the Array<T> in typescript/angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular8, generic-collections

I have an Angular 8 app.

Below is one of my models in typescript.

```
export class Movie
{
  title:string;
  tickets: Array<Ticket>;
}

export class Ticket
{
   name:string;
   price:number;
}
```

In one of the components (movie), when I access the `movie` object, `tickets` is not getting initialized.

movie.component.ts

```
export class MovieComponent
{
  movieObj:Movie;

  constructor()
  {
    this.movieObj = new Movie();
    console.log(this.movieObj); // outputs title value but not tickets
   //console.log(this.movieObj.tickets[0].name); //undefined 
  }
}
```

While checking the Array type in TypeScript, it's an interface. (We cannot create an object of an interface)

How to initialize the Array in typescript/angular?

Thanks!

Comment: You just create the array `arr = []`. You then only put whatever type you've declared for it. If you try to put anything else, the compiler will stop you.

Answer (score 0):

> **You can `initialize` it in the class itself.**

```
export class Movie
{
  title:string = 'Movie';
  tickets: Array<Ticket> = [{name: 'Ticket', price: 300}];
}
```

### [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5dvnse)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
export class Movie
{
  title:string = 'Movie';
  tickets: Ticket[] = [];
}
export class Ticket
{
   name:string;
   price:number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some logic while creating tickets, you have to use `constructor` of `Movie` class.

You can initialize the property with an empty array of tickets using:

```
export class Movie
{
  title:string;
  tickets: Ticket[] = [];
}
```

It doesn't matter using `Ticket[]`(shorthand syntax) or `Array<Ticket>`(generic syntax).
There isn't any semantic difference and they're completely equivalent.